# GitLab -> difference between Environment and Runner?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I happened to see the concept of "Environment" while I reading the docs teaching how to write an right ".gitlab-ci.yml" file. And I am eager to know the difference between the property "Environment" of a job and the "Runner" runs my jobs ?

I ventured to guess that Runner should be the container running my jobs, However, "Environment" should be the container where I will deploy my app in the future.Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Environment" is a "place" of deployment. You can have a testing environment, a staging one and of course a production environment. You can read more about it here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments.html#environments

"Runner" is just a worker process processing your CI job - it't not connected to your app - it just picks up your job from the pipeline, runs it and takes another job (possibly from completly different app). Here's more info about runners: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/README.html